# How to use the build in CRUD-Modell for insert and escape the datas on Codeigniter4

Tags: codeigniter-4

I tried to understand the new ways and possibilities with Codeigniter4.

I see a shorter way by the build in Crud-Model to do the simplest job with a bit less of code.

Do I insert new datas in the controller with this code, after I setup the myModel with the protected variables.?

```
$this->myModel->insert(['filed1' => 'value1,
                    'field2'  =>$this->request->getPost('field')...
                ]));
```

So that works fine.

Now I want to make it a bit more secure and I want to insert only escaped values.

For that CodeIgniter has a lot of built-in functions/helpers. So I try to use "escape()" in this way

```
 $this->myModel->insert(escape(['filed1' => 'value1,
                        'field2'  =>$this->request->getPost('field')...
                    ])));
```

but it failed with the error "Call to undefined function App\Controllers\escape()"

So how I can insert only escaped values into my db with the nicest/fastest code/Way may which is supported with the build-in basic Crud functions?

Thanks to teach/help me in this point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`escape` doesn't work in a global context because that method is a member of the `Database` class (or rather, a parent class that implements the ConnectionInterface interface).

`esc` *is* a global function, which is why that works in a global context.

However, `esc` is designed to escape data that's going [into web pages](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=esc#esc), not databases.

The good news is, if you're using **Query Builder** methods, then input is already escaped for you [automatically](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html):

> It also allows for safer queries, since the values are escaped
> automatically by the system.

If for some reason you still need to manually escape input (e.g. using basic queries), there are a [few options](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#escaping-queries), including the `escape` method you were trying to use earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I find a first way with "esc()"

```
$this->myModel->insert(['filed1' => esc('value1'),
                        'field2'  => esc($this->request->getPost('field'))...
                    ]));
```

maybe there is a better way or someone has another sugeestion?